# Data is greater than post size

Tags: magento-1.9

what should we do if data size greater than post size ?

Comment: provide more detail

Comment: i create multi select drop down and it show all brands value in my dropdown  now the issue is tha when i select some brands it save but when i select all brands it show nothing in post ?log

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `apache with php then either set the below to .htaccess or for nginx i think you need to set the same in nginx conf file`.

**php_value post_max_size 50M** // Set as per your post value size

Comment: where in htaccess i mean how add this i just past axact code in htaccess?

Comment: whats your web server apache or nginx ?

Comment: my server is niginx

Comment: set it to php.ini. Just add a line post_max_size=50M like this.

Comment: etc/php/7.0/apache2$ nano php.ini i open this file and made change but info php show 8M

Comment: if you put a phpinfo() in a root file and run..it will show all the php configuration settings...along with that it also shows php.ini path over there. Check that path and make that change on that file only.

Comment: yes its showing this path

Comment: if you are using PHP-FAM fastcgi manager then restart php-fpm or php5-fpm or just restart apache or nginx. Because your changes wont reflect until you restart your service.

Comment: ok i have more than 1075 values in my select dropdwon so memory will be issue?

Comment: But your form will select only 1 value right?..because its a select box. So it will send only 1 value for that particular field. So shouldnt be an issue.

Comment: no issue is that i select mulitiple values  if i select some values it show in post but when i select all values which are more than1075 then is show noting in log getting my point

Comment: Have you increased post_max_size. If not try to increase it and check. You can try to set it to any arbitrary bigger value and check. If still doesnt work then try to increase max_input_vars ...check this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399315/how-to-increase-maximum-post-variable-in-php

Comment: great you are hero thanx